# Solr Boosting specific field values

Tags: solr, solr5

I'm trying to boost the score for documents returned from a search in solr.

The boost I want to achieve is something along the lines of:

```
field1:(value1)^5 OR field2:(value2)^2
```

**If the document does have field1 matching value1, boost by 5.
If document does have field2 matching value2, boost by 2.**

The documents have many fields, let's call them field1, field2... and may be missing certain fields.

The documents do not need to have field1 or field2 matching value1, value2 respectively.

I have other filter queries such as:

```
fq: field1:[* TO *]  <- checking for presence of

fq: field3: ("something" "somethingelse")

fq: field4: 1
```

I am grouping my results by a certain field not being used in any of the queries.

Raw query parameters:

```
group=true&group.facet=true&group.field=anIndependentField
```

I am using the same fq's with tried different query parsers.

There are enough documents in solr with field1:value1 and/or field2:value2 as well as other values for those fields.

So far I've tried using the query parsers:

1. Standard Query Parser

> method a) q: field1:(value1)^5 OR field2:(value2)^2 // no results
>
> method b) q: *:* OR field1:(value1)^5 OR field2:(value2)^2 // no results
>
> method c) q: (value1)^5 OR (value2)^2  // incorrect. looks for complete match.
>
> method d) q: (value1)^5 (value2)^2 // incorrect. looks for complete match

2. EDisMax Query Parser

(defType=edismax)

q: *:*

```
bq: field1:(value1)^5 OR field2:(value2)^2
```

Problem with this one is that results are not in expected order.
A document that has field1:somethingElse and field2:somethingElse2 got a higher score than a document that has field1: somethingElse and field2:value2.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or has a suggestion to improve the relevancy of my search queries?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the `bq` argument? `&bq=field1:value1^5&bq=field2:value2^2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bf parameter of eDismax queryParser in the following way:

```
bf=if(termfreq(field1,"value1"),5,if(termfreq(field2,"value2"),2,1))
```

Please find below the complete query.

```
https://<MY_SERVER_NAME>:9443/solr/<MY_COLLECTION>/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&bf=if(termfreq(field1%2C%22value1%22)%2C3%2Cif(termfreq(field2%2C%22value2%22)%2C2%2C0))
```